# using sendBeacon in WordPress ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, navigator, sendbeacon

I am trying to use an ajax request on page unload/visibilityChange. I found `navigator.sendBeacon` is a best option for that. I tried using it with WordPress, the request is being sent but I get 'POST 400 bad request' error.

Here is my js code:

```
let array_data_on_unload = [url1, url2, url3]; //array of urls
let unload_delete_data = {
        action: 'delete_on_unload',
        source_urls: JSON.stringify(array_data_on_unload)
    };
        
    if(array_data_on_unload.length >= 1){
        let result = navigator.sendBeacon(window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', unload_delete_data);
        console.log(result); //returns true in console
    }
```

My php code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_on_unload', 'delete_on_unload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_on_unload', 'delete_on_unload' );

function delete_on_unload(){
    $response = array('success' => true);
    
    $file_urls = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['source_urls']));
    
    foreach($file_urls as $file_url){
      //do the delete operation
    }
    exit(json_encode($response));
}
```

Why is this returning `POST [domain]/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)` error?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. we can't change header in `sendBeacon`. So for it to send the data as json object. we can send it as formData();. see below code

```
    let unload_formData = new FormData();
        
    unload_formData.append('action', 'delete_on_unload');
    unload_formData.append('source_urls', JSON.stringify(array_data_on_unload));
```